I can't edit vector element in a leetcode problem
class Solution {
public:
 
    string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& vct) {
        int z = vct[0].size() -1  ;
        int len = vct.size();
        int count = 0;

        salto:  
        for (int i=0 ; i<len && z > 0 ; i++) cout << vct[i]<< " " <<  z<< endl;

        for (int i=0 ; i<len-1 ; i++){
            if (vct[i] != vct[i+1]) 
                for (int i=0 ; i<len ; i++) {
                    vct[i] = vct[i].substr(0,z);
                }
                z-=1;
                goto salto;  
        }
    }

I'm trying to do a problem in c++ on leetcode that consists in finding the common initial of a series of strings, the idea of ​​my algorithm is to check if the strings are equal through a for loop that compares each element of the starting vector with the next, then if they are different the last letter is eliminated while if they are equal the remaining string is returned which should be the common part, the problem is that by executing the code the program stops truncating the strings after the second, for example, with an input vector 'flower, flow, flight', the output is
flower
flow
flight
flower
flow
flight
flowe
flow
fligh
flow
flow
flig
flow
flow
flig
flow
flow
flig

and so on to infinity, and it stops at flow, the strange thing is that if I do cout << vct[i].substr(0,z) << vct[i] << endl I get that v1 and v1substr have different values ​​even though I did vct = vct.substr() right before, in particular vct[i].substr(0,z) printed has the value that I would expect vct to have but instead it is not modified. also if I do vct = vct.substr(0,1) I can modify vct beyond the "flow" however this does not happen using the variable z. Can someone help me?
I tried to move the elements of the vector that leetcode gave me into another variable created by me but I got the same result. Furthermore, even by modifying a string inside the vector at the beginning of the code, all the modifications of the strings inside the vector are blocked by trying to modify them using the variables of the for loop even though the compiler does not give errors

The indentation doesn't correspond to the actual structure of the code, which may be all or part of the problem. z -= 1 and goto salto; are not in the if block. Avoid leaving out the braces around the body of conditional and looping structures.

And try to avoid using goto.

There is no path for that function to return.  How did you expect it to end?

You may fail LeetCode with a Time Limit Exceeded error because your algorithm takes too long or has too many steps in it.  Try a simpler, shorter algorithm.

In general if you have a goto in your code you're either solving a really interesting problem or have a bug. Sometimes both. I've found that the effort invested in getting a goto through a code review and explaining why the goto was the right choice to those that follow exceeds the cost of writing the code without the goto almost every time.

You had no way to exit.  The goto should be replaced by a while loop that runs until z becomes 1.  This seems to work on your data:
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:

    string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& vct) {
        int z = vct[0].size() -1  ;
        int len = vct.size();
        int count = 0;

        while( z > 1 )
        {
            for (int i=0 ; i<len && z > 0 ; i++) 
                cout << vct[i]<< " " <<  z<< endl;

            for (int i=0 ; i<len-1 ; i++){
                if (vct[i] != vct[i+1]) 
                    for (int i=0 ; i<len ; i++) {
                        vct[i] = vct[i].substr(0,z);
                    }
                z-=1;
            }
        }
        return vct[0];
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<string> data;
    data.push_back( "flower" );
    data.push_back( "flow" );
    data.push_back( "flight" );
    Solution s;
    cout << s.longestCommonPrefix( data ) << "\n";
}


I know the final idea is to replace the goto with a recursive function, however I haven't thought carefully yet about how to exit since I still haven't managed to get to the desired result and I haven't yet considered the problem of terminating the program.

This is not an appropriate use case for recursion.

Isuuse With your Code:

Using goto creates complex control flow that    can easily lead to
infinite loops if not handled carefully. The loop    structure lacks
a clear exit condition.

Modifying the vector elements with vct[i] = vct[i].substr(0,z)
directly does not affect the subsequent comparisons correctly
because the original strings remain unchanged outside the loop context.


Modification:

Removal of goto: The refactored code uses a simple while loop to
manage control flow, which is easier to read and maintain.

A while loop checks if the current string starts with the prefix. If
not, the prefix is shortened one character at a time until a match
is found or the prefix becomes empty.


    for (int i = 1; i < vct.size(); i++) {
        // While the current string does not start with the prefix
        while (vct[i].find(prefix) != 0) {
            // Reduce the prefix by one character
            prefix = prefix.substr(0, prefix.size() - 1);
            // If the prefix is empty, there is no common prefix
            if (prefix.empty()) return "";
        }
    }
    return prefix;


Start by adding braces to your if statement.
       for (int i=0 ; i<len-1 ; i++){
         if (vct[i] != vct[i+1]) 
           for (int i=0 ; i<len ; i++) {
             vct[i] = vct[i].substr(0,z);
           }
           z-=1;
           goto salto;  
       }

Is actually:
       for (int i=0 ; i<len-1 ; i++){
         if (vct[i] != vct[i+1]) 
           for (int i=0 ; i<len ; i++) {
             vct[i] = vct[i].substr(0,z);
           }
         z-=1;
         goto salto;  
       }

Your loop is only running once before the goto: is called.

You should show a solution that doesn't have the goto.

@ThomasMatthews I could, but I don't think OP is looking for a solution to the particular LeetCode problem. They're just wondering why their code isn't behaving as expected.
